# Insert data from one table to another table while the target table has a primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server I have a table as RawTable (temp) which gets fed by a CVS, let's say it has 22 columns in it. Then, I need to copy existing records (ONLY FEW COLUMNs NOT ALL) into another table as Visitors which is not temporary table.

Visitor table has an ID column as INT and that is primary key and incremental.

RawData table

```
id  PK, int not null
VisitorDate  Varchar(10)
VisitorTime  Varchar(11)
```

Visitors table

```
VisitorID, PK, big int, not null
VisitorDate,  Varchar(10), null
VisitorTime   Varchar(11), null
```

So I did:

```
insert into [dbo].[Visitors] ( [VisitorDate], [VisitorTime])    
select [VisitorDate], [VisitorTime]
from RawTable   /*this is temp table */
```

Seems SQL Server doesn't like this method so it throws

*Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'VisitorID', table 'TS.dbo.Visitors'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated.*

How can I keep Sql Server not to complain about the primary key? this column as you know better will be fed by sql server itself.

Any idea?

Comment: You need to make it an `IDENTITY` column or give it a default value using a `sequence` if you want SQL Server to maintain it. Script out the `CREATE TABLE` as doesn't seem that this is the case.

Comment: Please provide actual DDL for both tables (excerpted if necessary) instead of describing it in broken English.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens check it out now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because your visitors table has an ID column that is the primary key doesn't mean that the server will supply your ID values for you. if you want SQL to provide the ID's then you need to alter the table definition and make the visitorsId column an IDENTITY column.

Otherwise, you can psuedo-create these id's during the insert with the ROW_NUMBER function -

```
DECLARE @maxId INT;

SELECT @maxId = (SELECT MAX(visitorsId) FROM dbo.visitors);

INSERT INTO  [dbo].[Visitors] ( [visitorsId],[VisitorDate], [VisitorTime])    
SELECT @maxId + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY visitorDate), [VisitorDate], [VisitorTime]
from RawTable   /*this is temp table */
```

Comment: no no no.. way different. in SQL you can define a column as an IDENTITY.. [newColumn] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY where the first "1" is the seed value to start and the second "1" is the increment amount.

Comment: I am looking at the drop-down (date types) but don't see a type as IDENTITY. What am I missing? In Mysql it seems easier

Comment: The data type will still be INT or BIGINT. I'm not familiar with the GUI for table creation. Let me see if I can poke around. IDENTITY is just a keyword for the server.

Comment: oh now I know! you mean INT datatype then in the properties I can set it to Identity(1,1) or (1,2) and etc.

Comment: Ok, under "column properties" there is an entry for "Identity Specification" which you will want to expand it and set the first entry underneath to yes

Comment: Nick, any way of doing this while changing some of the data types?